# sorting MySql query by two columns that are previous and next fk for same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

So I wanted to know if anyone know or have a general idea on how to sort the returned query of a playlist, I keep the NEXT_ID and PREVIOUS_ID in the same table as SONG_ID

the table structure:

```
PLAYLIST_SONG_ID PK,
PLAYLIST_ID,
SONG_ID,
SONG_NAME,
ARTIST,
PREVIOUS_PLAYLIST_SONG_ID FK TO PLAYLIST_SONG_ID ,
NEXT_PLAYLIST_SONG_ID FK TO PLAYLIST_SONG_ID
```

I thought on putting `NULL` as the signs for start and end of playlist.
In Addition, if someone has a better idea on how to build the table, It will be appreciated as well.

Thanks

Edit: So, Is there anyone that can supply an example of the needed query?

Comment: please guys, can someone suggest a solution for this question?
i would appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like a PLAYLIST_POSITION  column and sort by that column. 
This should be much easy to handle than next / previous. Just use position + 1 as next and position - 1 as previous.

Comment: Yes, but what if you want to delete a song in the middle of the list or just change the order by one query?

Comment: That is a tradeoff. ;) You could also use 'first position greater than current' as next. This way you don't need to change anything when deleting in the middle

Comment: that doesnt help as well because its not just greater than,I wanna be able to change existing records positions in the same list.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` would work, but its a little pron to bugs because it is very possible that NULL entries could end up in your final table for unwanted reasons and then that would be interpreted as a playlist end which may not be what you want because it could make a bug even harder to detect. I would personally use `-1` instead of `NULL` to denote where my playlist started and stopped. I'm assuming here that your id values and ints such that this would work.

The reason `-1` is preferred is because you would have to explicitly set your playlist start and stop to `-1` each time. You would be able to rest assured that it would be tough for some type of bug to randomly place `-1` at the selected row, much more so than `NULL`. Also the int type in mysql always start at `1` (by default, It doesn't stop you from doing weird stuff though) so negative numbers will not be any of the id values that compose your table. Which means that you never have to worry about `-1` falling into place as a id, you can safely be certain that it is always the start or end of a playlist.

Edit: However to actually solve your question, an approach would be to include another table that you could join with your song table. This additional table maps order to a song for a playlist and so it is a many to many join table. It could have the following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `songs_orders` (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    song_id int,
    order_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: I agree that using the -1 or any other option for that matter is better than just using NULLs. i will use that idea.
However, that still doesn't answer my question. I wanted assistance with the way i should build the query for selecting the list perfectly ordered.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Call me nuts but I dont see how that will do the trick...
lets say i have two relevant tables: tbl_songs and tbl_playlists.
tbl_playlist holds the playlist_id, song_id and the prev, next.
how this is gonna help me if I want to add a song in the middle of the list? i need to know how to change the places in the middle.

Comment: @user2374811 You need to review how many to many relations work in MySQL. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/databases/sql-for-beginners-part-3-database-relationships/

Comment: thank you for your assistance, but you clearly dont understand my problem.

Comment: @user2374811 fair enough, its possible. Have you reviewed join tables lately?

Comment: yes. I cant see how that solves my issue.
Lets say I have a playlist with 20 songs. each playlist_song_id has the before and after songs so it will know where to travel next.
just for example:
playlist_song_id is 1153
the playlist_id is 11
the song_id is 52
next playlist_song_id  855
prev playlist_song_id  is 689

how would you enter a song between this one and the next?